# jQuery change event, problems with form serialization in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I am working on a basket/cart on a webshop.

What I want to accomplish is to update the changes in quantity or variation selection, the customer is making on the cart overview page.

Now to do this with jQuery, I am trying with a change() event on selectors: 
.cartItem input, .cartItem select

The basket overview is currently listing one item each tr/row in a table. 
I was then thinking in order to make serialize() possible, I need to have an `form` for each item

I applied a form open `<form class="cartItem">` just before each `<tr>` and and closing `</form>` after `</tr>`. Here is my code for complete understanding: http://jsfiddle.net/g2Pmu/1/

But it doesn't work. Am i thinking wrong?

Currently my code has two errors:

```
1. jQuery doesnt set change event on .cartItem input?
2. jQuery cannot serialize the .cartItem form?
```

An success serialization on change, I am looking for, is:

```
co_product=78&co_variant=M&co_qty=3
```

Why does jQuery not think that my form is a valid form to serialize, and how can i solve this in a proper way?

Please comment for any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to me is your markup structure, that is an invalid markup because of this:

```
 <tbody>
    <form class="cartItem">
    <input type="hidden" name="co_product" value="78" />
    <tr>
```

You just cannot have a form inside between a `<tbody>` and `<tr>`.

You can follow a valid Markup structure like:

```
<form class="cartItem">
   <input type="hidden" name="co_product" value="78" />
   <table>
       // all the form elems
   </table>
</form>
```

---

#### [Demo updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2Pmu/2/)

---

Or you can have a single form and place all the hidden inputs in any of the tds available to the trs like this:

```
<form class="cartItem">
<table class="table table-bordered tbl-cart">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Name</td>
            <td>Variant</td>
            <td class="td-qty">Quantity</td>
            <td>Unit Price</td>
            <td>Sub Total</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><!--put the hidden input here-->
                <input type="hidden" name="co_product" value="78" /> <a href="/p/nike-airmax-10">Nike AirMax 1.0</a>

            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="co_variant" class="item-variant">
                    <option value="S" selected="selected">S</option>
                    <option value="M">M</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="co_qty" value="2" class="item-qty form-control text-center" />
            </td>
            <td class="price_unit">249,00 SEK</td>
            <td class="price_display">498,00 SEK</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><!--and here-->
                <input type="hidden" name="co_product" value="77" /><a href="/p/46-jedi-morgonrock">Nike Pinky</a>

            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="co_variant" class="item-variant">
                    <option value="S" selected="selected">S</option>
                    <option value="M">M</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="co_qty" value="1" class="item-qty form-control text-center" />
            </td>
            <td class="price_unit">499,00 SEK</td>
            <td class="price_display">499,00 SEK</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" align="right">Total</td>
            <td class="total" colspan="2"><b>997,00 SEK</b>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

and you can try changing your jQuery little bit like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.cartItem input, select').change(function () {
       var me = $(this);
       var form = $(me).closest('tr').find(':input').serialize();
       alert(form);
       return false;
    });
});
```

update to this line :

```
$(me).closest('tr').find(':input').serialize();
```

---

#### [Another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2Pmu/3/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works - Although is there no way around, must I have one table for each item? It kind of mess up the css rules

Comment: @Karem try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g2Pmu/3/ updated one with the markup and jQuery.

Comment: This is the solution! Thank you. +1 for two solutions

Comment: @karem You are welcome. Glad it is been a help to you.

Comment: Why do you jQuer-ify the `me` variable twice?